# How can I get the Bloomberg BDH function through Python with xbbg?

Tags: python, bloomberg

How can I get the Bloomberg BDH data through Python? In BDH it works with

> `=BDH("5 hk equity","High","2022-07-05 09:30:00","2022-07-05 16:00:00","Direction","V","BarType","Trade","BarSize","390","TimeZone","Hong_Kong","Dates","H")`

in excel Bloomberg API

I have tried the python xbbg package but can't get the answer. the code is as below:
I want to get the day-high data within a specific time period.(09:30:00-16:00:00)

```
from xbbg import blp

stocklist = '9988 hk equity'

df_high = blp.bdh(tickers=stocklist, flds=['High'],start_date='2022-07-05 09:30:00', end_date='2022-07-05 16:00:00',Direction="V",BarType="Trade",BarSize="390",TimeZone="Hong_Kong",Dates="H")

print(df_high)
```

Comment: bdh is for historical, not intraday data I think.

Answer (score 0):

I like the functionality of `xbbg` as a Bloomberg wrapper, but its documentation leaves a little to be desired. On the other hand, you have the python source, so you can track through it, if you have the will.

In Excel, BDH covers both historical and intraday data, even though they are two different requests as far as the Bloomberg API is concerned. You are after 'Intraday Bar' data, and the `xbbg` function is `bdib`.

```
from xbbg import blp

stocklist = '5 HK Equity'

df = blp.bdib(ticker=stocklist, dt='2022-07-05',ref='EquityHongKong',typ='TRADE',session='day',interval=390) 

print(df[stocklist].high.iloc[0])
```

The base Bloomberg API uses UTC times, unless you supply a timezone. `xbbg` uses the idea of an `exchange` to determine the timezone and session times. This is stored in a configuration file in the package directory.

The relevant extract is:

```
EquityHongKong:
  tz: Asia/Hong_Kong
  allday: [845, 1615]
  day: [930, 1600]
  am: [930, 1200]
  pm: [1300, 1600]
  pre: [845, 930]
  post: [1601, 1615]
```

hence specifying `ref='EquityHongKong'` and `session='day'` gives the time span you want.